# Do Loop + Match

Tags: vba, excel, match, do-loops

I am looking to delete everything that does not match my inputbox value. However, it seems like the loop I am using is not working at all! It seems the code does not read the loop. The loop should delete the entire row of each cell in the column E that does not match my inputbox variable. I run the code, insert the value in the input box and nothing gets deleted.

Can someone **PLEASE help me??**

```
'Get the Tenrox code to be deleted
  tenroxcode = InputBox("Insert the Tenrox Code that you want to keep")

'Find and delete all unnecessary tenrox codes
 r = Application.Match(tenroxcode, Columns("E"), 0)

Do While IsError(r)
  Rows(r).EntireRow.Delete
  r = Application.Match(tenroxcode, Columns("E"), 0)
Loop
```

Comment: Help us help you, by *explicitly* detailing what you mean by "the loop I am using is not working at all".

Comment: If tenroxcode is anywhere in column E, it will always be found. This method cannot be used for NOT conditions.

Comment: BTW, your inputbox prompt contradicts your narrative.

Comment: I fixed the msg box!

Comment: If there is a lot to delete, use autofilter and delete the visible row.

Comment: It seems the code does not read the loop. The loop should delete the entire row of each cell in the column E that does not match my inputbox variable. I run the code, insert the value in the input box and nothing gets deleted.

Comment: Add this to your question please, rather than clarifying in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
tenroxcode = InputBox("Insert the Tenrox Code that you want to keep")

With Worksheets("Sheet1") ' change as needed

    With .UsedRange.Columns(5) 'assumes data is in column a1 and contiguous across cells

        If Not .Find(tenroxcode, lookat:=xlWhole) is Nothing Then

            .AutoFilter 1, "<>" & tenroxcode
            .offset(1).specialcells(xlCellTypeVisible).entirerow.delete 'offset so header row stays

        End If 

    End With

    .AutoFilterMode = False

End With
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do this is to use the Autofilter to filter on anything that doesn't match your condition, and then delete the rows. And I'd suggest turning your data into an Excel Table first, because it simplifies code.

Simply fire up the macro recorder, and you'll get code like this::

```
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:= _
        "<>SomeValue", Operator:=xlAnd
    Range("Table1[Column1]").Select
    Selection.EntireRow.Delete 
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1
```

That should be enough to get you started.